# getline() not working on redirected Linux standard input

Tags: c++, linux, getline

I am debugging a file on my computer. Rather than use keyboard input, I am running the program like so:

```
./main < input.txt
```

There is a section of code in my program that looks like this:

```
do {
    cout << "Type \"STOP\" when done: ";
    getline(cin, myString);
    cout << endl;
    if (myString == "STOP") {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Input next line: " << endl;
    getline(cin, myString2);
    cout << endl;

    // do something with the two strings

} while (myString != "STOP");
```

Instead of stopping when there is a line in the file that equals `"STOP"` (no quotes), it keeps looping forever. Earlier, there is a `cin >> myInt`, but I made sure to use `cin.ignore()` after every call. It works fine if I type in the values without redirecting.

This is the output:

```
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
Type "STOP" when done:
...
```

Please help me figure out what is going on!

Comment: I should add that I also tried `getline(cin, throwAwayString)` instead of `cin.ignore()` to no avail.

Comment: Is myString a string or char array?

Comment: @Eugene It's a string from the C++ standard library, same as the `throwAwayString` I tried in the previous comment

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to find out what is the value of  `myString`. Read carefully the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Using gdb, it shows that `myString` is "" the first time, then it's off by one in the input

Comment: So you probably found your bug. Perhaps examine also the input file (it might contain non-printable characters), e.g. with `hexdump`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the input file is fine, just line-separated strings made of ordinary letters or integers

Comment: You could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). But please question your own code before supposing that the C++ standard library is buggy. `getline` is working as documented!

Comment: Always check the boolean value of the result of `getline`, just like any other input function. Assume it may fail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out! Like Basile Starynkevitch suggested, the problem was not with my code but with the input file. I wrote the input file on my Windows laptop and ran it from a Linux VM, and there was some confusion about the DOS line endings that caused the error.

Because Windows terminates their lines with `\r\n` and *nix terminates them with just `\n`, the `cin.ignore()` ignored the `\r` but not the `\n`, which was being read into the `getline()`.

Solution: simply write the input file in Linux, or use the "unix" line endings in your editor of choice (usually something like `View -> Line Endings -> Unix)`.

Curse you blasted "standards" developers!

Comment: Some editors (noteably Notepad++) allow to configure the line endings.

Answer (score -1):

Try simply using the `cin` command instead. For example:

```
do {
    cout << "Type \"STOP\" when done: ";
    cin >> myString;
    cout << endl;
    if (myString == "STOP") {
        break;
    }
} while (myString != "STOP");
```

This would eliminate the need for the `getline()` function, because you have no need to store the entire line when the user is only supposed to type one word (`"STOP"`). Even if the user were to type more than one word in this situation, the compiler would only take the first word.

Comment: `cin` won't work because I need to take lines of data, I'm using those in the program. It needs to be `getline()`